The earthly life of Jesus in Paul's letters
Anyone respond to Richard carrier claim in Romans 1:3 that the Genesis 2:7 means that Adam was manufactured I thought it said Adam came into being he was he came into being γίνομαι

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

I think this "question" needs improved to help us provide an answer.  1. What is the question?  2. Provide a summary of Richard Carrier's  analysis sufficient enough to provide a thoughtful answer.  We currently don't have anything to go on unless we research for your question. This summary should provide some analysis of it's own.  Something like:  "Richard Carrier says [summary of his point].  He backs it up with [summarized list of his perspective].  But, I thought, [texts that seemingly contradict]."  Follow this up with the question regarding his and/or your texts.

at least provide a link to the article you are referring to. Not many participants here ready Carrier as much as you apparently do. '-)

The website here exists to analyse the scripture, hermeneutically. We are not here to examine the writings of someone outside of scripture. I suggest a change of focus.

@NigelJ ... . The fact that a non-biblical writer has put the question in the OPs mind should not be an obstacle.  Indeed, we are encouraged to give credit to those whose research we use. But I agree the question is not up to snuff in terms of BHse standards.

I think the OP misunderstood what Carrier said about Adam. He explains his idea about 'manufactured' in this article. He says:

My proposal [is] that when Paul said Jesus was “made from the sperm of
David” (which is literally what Paul says in the original Greek), he
meant that literally: God used the actual semen of David to form a
body for Jesus to occupy in order to accomplish his atonement
sacrifice as spelled out in Philippians 2.

In this article he is not saying that Adam was manufactured but that Jesus was. Adam, he says, "came into being" or was born. Carrier's writing is clumsy here. Here is my interpretation:

It is an indisputable fact that when Paul says this [about Jesus], he
uses a word {γενομένου} he only uses of manufactured, not birthed bodies... {Paul uses different words when}
referring to Adam’s body).

Logically, if he thinks that Jesus was manufactured from David's sperm, such a process was not involved with Adam.
Conclusion: I admit that I may have misunderstood Carrier here because his writing is confusing. But I think it was the OP who misunderstood what Carrier wrote. He was saying the Jesus' body was manufactured from David's sperm but that Adam came into being another way.

Thanks for pointing to the article (though I'm a little concerned we're doing someone's homework for them).  Richard Carrier has a profound lack of understanding of Semantics, especially as it relates across languages (like Greek to English, he conflates the two).  I haven't read very much of him, and don't plan to, but it appears he has a hyper-literalist understanding of lexical semantics.  There are no Lexicographers that would hold to such a view.  The contradictions to such a view are innumerable.

+1. Very helpful answer.

Adam was manufactured in the sense of being formed by Elohim YWHY from the dust of the ground and the breath of life in Genesis 2:7. That is how Adam came into being, or said was manufactured.
In the strictest use of language of Genesis, Adam was not created or made, he was formed. Created, made, and formed are not synonyms. Created is existence out of nothing, made is existence by manipulation of an already existing creation, and formed is further manipulation of something made. More precisely it was YHWH of the Elohim who manufactured Adam. Genesis contains these three distinct words: created, made, formed.
It makes sense to use the word manufactured the same as formed because to manufacture a hat oneself has to have the earth and animals already existing. Then the earth and animals can be manipulated to get the raw materials necessary to make the hat. Then the raw materials have to be further manipulated into becoming a hat. A hat is surely not a creation or made. A hat is formed.
And I explained how formed means the same as manufactured. Therefore in agreement that Adam was manufactured. Adam was formed because the dust of the earth and breath of life already existed. The dust of the earth came into existence as being made from the created earth.
I’m not exactly sure what Paul means. It could mean Jesus was made by the actual semen of King David which itself would be a miracle. Or not and Paul meant Jesus was made of the seed of David because both Mary and Joseph were descendants of King David. Like I said I’m not sure what Paul means because I’m not even convinced that Paul believed in the virgin birth or anything else written in the gospels of Matthew, Mark, and Luke about the genologies.
Paul agreed for resurrection of the dead Jesus and that Jesus was the messiah (Christ)and king of the high priest and nation (Son of God) and rabbi (Lord) of them all as evident by 1 Timothy 1:4. I don’t accept that Paul, John, or any of the authors of the gospels necessarily believed Jesus was God. As far as I know Thomas was the only one who specifically said in John 20:8 “my Lord and my God.” after touching the resurrected Jesus. Lord and God are not the same meaning. If you don’t understand the Lord and rabbi are synonymous read John 20 very carefully in the words of Mary Magdalene.
